# Problems using Console.Readkey method in VB.Net with BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, console

I'm trying to build a simulation of Conway's Game of Life using VB Console (I'm weird like that.) Things are *kind of* working. The program takes place within four loops with separate boolean conditions: Pause, Finish, Clear and Quit, from the innermost to the outermost. Controlling everything is a BackgroundWorker that reads Keypresses and changes all the Boolean variables. Only sometimes when using a BackgroundWorker and Console.Readkey, I get this thing where it takes two times to read a Keypress. I've had it in other projects too and I can't figure out why. When I pause the program it's clearly waiting for a keypress on both threads, but it's only when I press it the first time that the debugger prompts me to give a keypress. It's not a major problem, but all the same, I'd like to know if there's anything I can do to eliminate this.

This is the main sub, excluding the declarations:

```
Do Until Quit = True 'This block repeats until Quit is true
        Start = False : Finish = False : Pause = False : Quit = False : Iterate = False : Clear = False
        Generation = 0 'This resets the Generation counter to 0
        ClearArray(Board) 'This resets a 2D boolean array to false.
        UpdateTitle(Generation) 'This updates the Console.Title to show the current generation.

        DrawBorder(Board, Offset, ConsoleColor.Cyan, BorderBlock) 'This draws an ASCII border around the grid.
        DrawBoard(Board, Offset) 'This draws the physical grid itself.

        WriteMessage(1, BoardDimensions(1) - 1, Offset) 'This writes a line below the grid prompting user input.
        ObtainInitialSetup(Board, Offset) 'This sub links to a bunch of other subs allowing the user to input an initial pattern.
        TransferArrayContents(Board, BoardMemory) 'This stores the contents of the pattern the user has entered into a memory array.
        Clear = False

        Do Until Clear = True 'This block repeats until Clear is true
            TransferArrayContents(BoardMemory, Board) 'This recalls the saved pattern from memory. If a user presses "Stop" then all generation
            'will cease and this is where the board is reset.
            DrawBoard(Board, Offset) 'The board is redrawn.
            WriteMessage(2, BoardDimensions(1) - 1, Offset)

            Do 'This block waits for the user to confirm before starting.
                Keypress = Console.ReadKey(True)
                If Keypress.Key = StartKey Then Start = True : Finish = False : Clear = False : Quit = False : Pause = False
                If Keypress.Key = QuitKey Then Finish = True : Clear = True : Quit = True
                If Keypress.Key = ClearKey Then Finish = True : Clear = True
                'The program does not start until a user presses Start, Clear or Quit.
            Loop Until Start = True Or Finish = True Or Clear = True Or Quit = True

            If Quit = False Then WriteMessage(3, BoardDimensions(1) - 1, Offset)
            If Finish = False Then If BK.IsBusy = False Then BK.RunWorkerAsync()
            'The backgroundworker is called so long as it isn't already running.

            Do Until Finish = True 'This block repeats until Stop is true
                Iterate = False 'The Iterate condition allows the Loop to go through once.
                UpdateTitle(Generation) 'This updates the title.
                Generate(Board, CoordList, Generation, Survivals, Births) 'This sub does the calculation across the whole Board and changes
                'the values in the board for the next generation.
                DrawBoard(Board, Offset) 'This draws the new board.
                CheckPause(Offset, BoardDimensions(1) - 1) 'This sub holds the loop if Pause is true by inserting a new Do Loop.
            Loop
        Loop
    Loop

    BK.CancelAsync()
```

And this is the BackgroundWorker Sub:

```
Sub ReadBackgroundKey() Handles BK.DoWork
    Dim Keypress As ConsoleKeyInfo
    Do
        Keypress = Console.ReadKey(True)
        If Keypress.Key = StopKey Then 'Finish
            Quit = False
            Clear = False
            Finish = True
        ElseIf Keypress.Key = PauseKey Then 'Pause the generation.
            Quit = False
            Clear = False
            Finish = False
            Pause = Not Pause
        ElseIf Keypress.Key = QuitKey Then 'Quit the game.
            Quit = True
            Clear = True
            Finish = True
            Pause = False
        ElseIf Keypress.Key = StepKey Then 'Step a generation.
            Quit = False
            Clear = False
            Finish = False
            Pause = True
            Iterate = True
        ElseIf Keypress.Key = ClearKey Then 'Clear the board.
            Quit = False
            Clear = True
            Finish = True
            Pause = False
        End If
    Loop Until Quit = True Or Clear = True
End Sub
```

Also, if you notice anything horrible that no respectable programmer should ever do, all criticisms are welcome - I've only been doing VB half a year and I'm not very good yet.

I appreciate all thoughts and feedback :).

Edit: Also, I can't put "Hello" or any pleasant greeting at the start of the post, it gets wiped out o.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks to me like you have "Start = False : Finish = False : Pause = False : Quit = False : Iterate = False : Clear = False" Under the first loop, so every loop around it resets.

Not quite sure if that would do it though, honestly I'm less experienced, insanely drowsy, and craving caffeine.

Edit: Did some messing around with it, I'm having the same problem, also inside a loop, Will look into it more

Right, so through messing around in my spare time, I have come up with a not so convenient solution, let me test it a bit and then I'll post, just want to make sue it's not luck.

Yep, just luck. Thanks to my inexperience with console applications, I don't quite know the commands well enough to say for certain, but it could be a problem with focus.